# Align Checkbox with Label - what am i doing wrong?

Tags: css, forms, alignment

I have a fieldset with a div inside of it with labels and textboxes, labels and dropdowns as well as labels with checkboxes.  Labels w/ textboxes align well, Labels w/ dropdown aligns well.  However, i cannot get the checkbox to align with the label at all.  What am i doing wrong?

```
<div class="col1">
<label id="lblVehicleID" for="txtVehicleID" class="vehicle_label">Vehicle ID:</label>
<asp:TextBox ID="txtVehicleID" runat="server" class="vehicle_input"></asp:TextBox>

<label id="lblName" for="txtVehicleName"  class="vehicle_label">Vehicle Name:</label>
<asp:TextBox ID="txtVehicleName" runat="server"  class="vehicle_input"></asp:TextBox>

<label id="lblCategorization" for="txtCategorization"  class="vehicle_label">Categorization:</label>
<asp:TextBox ID="txtCategorization" runat="server"  class="vehicle_input">         </asp:TextBox>

<label id="lblDomicileCountry" for="ddlDomicileCountry" class="vehicle_label">Domicile Country:</label>
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlDomicileCountry" runat="server" CssClass="vehicle_dd"></asp:DropDownList>


<label id="lblUSOrganized" for="chkUSOrganized" class="vehicle_label">US Organized/Established:</label>
<asp:CheckBox ID="chkUSOrganized" runat="server" ></asp:CheckBox>


<label id="lblOfferedToNonUS" for="chkOfferedToNonUS" class="vehicle_label">Offered to Only Non-US:</label>
<asp:CheckBox ID="chkOfferedToNonUS" runat="server"></asp:CheckBox>

</div>
```

Here is the CSS:

```
    .col1 {
      width: 500px;
      border: 1px solid black;
      float: left;
      padding: 5px;
    }

    .vehicle_label {
       float:left;
       width: 190px;
       text-align:right;
       padding-right:12px;
       margin-top:12px;
       clear:left;
       font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    }

    .vehicle_input, .vehicle_dd {
       margin-top: 12px;
       width:175px;
    }
```

I have tried but to no avail:

```
 input[type=checkbox] + label {
 display: inline-block;
 margin-left: 0.5em;
 margin-right: 2em;
 line-height: 1em;
 }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated! I know there are questions similar to this one but have not been able to figure out what i am doing incorrectly.

Thank you

Comment: not an answer, but it's sometimes nice to put the checkbox inside the label, eliminating this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Checkboxes were just floating next to the other input elements, try clearing the float with a clearfix after the input elements;

```
<div class=".clearfix"></div>
```

I have created a working demo of your code here;
http://jsfiddle.net/BmM2x/1/

Comment: God bless you!!  That definitely worked.  However, it only worked when the controls were changed to html controls and not .net controls.  I will have to work with them this way.  Thank you for your help!